# Data not passing between server and jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using jQuery dataTable with AdminBSB Material Design Template with [datatable.net](https://datatables.net/) 
JSON Data is not passing between my jQuery table and server.

My sorting function is not working properly. Once I click sorting, all loaded data is not showing as no data in the table.

Here is my ajax code with API

```
$.ajax({
  //local
  url: "http://localhost/xxxxx/",

  //server
  //url: "http://18.206.116.36/xxxxxx/",

  dataType: 'json',
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) {

    var i = 0;
    var count = data.total;
    var estimatedTimeArr = [];

    $('#loading-data3').hide();


    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

      $('#remaining-time').append(
        "<tr><td>" + data.data[i].ASSIGNEE + "</td><td>" +
        data.data[i].totalEstimateTime + " hours</td><td>" +
        data.data[i].timeSpent + " hours</td><td>" +
        data.data[i].remainTime + " hours</td></tr>"
      ).dataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        paging: true,
        retrieve: true,
        searching: false,
        ajax: data.json
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't initialize plugin in every iteration of loop. Also doesn't make sense doing manual html insertion and using `serverside:true`. Don't appear to be setting up `serverside` properly

Comment: @charlietfl Still the same issue. Can you explain more in details